# Creating an expandable UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is like combo box, but it is not. I do not know how does it call. If you tap it, additional information will appear:

**Closed View**

[image: Closed view]

**Expanded View**

[image: Expanded view]

I can not search effective in google because I do not know what I search, I can only show.

Comment: It's a tableView with expanding and collapsing functionality

Comment: Go through this link for demo example...http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.in/2011/10/uitableview-display-and-hide-cells-as.html

Comment: Apple has WWDC video on collapsable table views. I think it was a 2010 session and the demo app was reused in a 2011 video also. Sorry I can't recall the name of the session but it was something about table views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using UITableView with custom cells. You use a normal tableview with disclosure button. Then when the user taps on the disclosure button(or select the row, if you want), you apply the custom cell to the selected row.

Try searching for:

- UITableView
- UITableViewCell
- accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath(for handling disclosure
  event)
- didSelectRowAtIndexPath(for handling row selection)

Answer (score 0):

It's a Customized `UITableView`.
For doing this you need to customize the `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`.

There are some third party controls available for doing this.

1. [SDNestedTable](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sdnestedtable)
2. [ComboBox iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/combobox-for-uitableview)
3. [CollapseClick](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/collapseclick)