# Show/Hide custom class elements when uitableviewcell is selcted

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to iOS development. I have doubt related to UITableViewCell height.

[image]

I am using one tableview, I have taken prototype cell in storyboard. The cell height I have given is 75. But what I need is when I select cell height will be increase and show 1 button (which is in black color in the image). The button is declared in UITableViewCell's custom class. Below of that image I have one label. If button is showing I need to place the label at the bottom of button or else in the place of button I need to show that label.

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an expandable UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763482/creating-an-expandable-uitableview)

Comment: i worked with it but it is not helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [tableView beginUpdates] and  [tableView endUpdates];

for Ex:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

 [self hideControlMethodsTable];//Declare method to hide when button tableview loads initially

 [tableList beginUpdates];
 [tableList deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

 CellRes =  (ReservationTableViewCell*) 
                  [tableList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cellSelectedFirstTime == true) {
            self.selectedRow   =    indexPath.row;
            [self showControlsMethodsTable];
            cellSelectedFirstTime = false;
        }
        else{
        if(self.selectedRow == indexPath.row){
        self.selectedRow  =  -1;
        [self hideControlMethodsTable];

    }
       else{
        self.selectedRow   =    indexPath.row;
        [self showControlsMethodsTable];

    }
   }
[tableList endUpdates];
}
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if(openForFirstCell  == true){


    if (cellSelectedFirstTime==true) {
        CellRes =  [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        return 180.;

    }

return 60;
    }

  }
```

Hope this helps you.